# Slide through blocks of multiple elements, advance whole block (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an arbitrary number of elements which I want to slide through. I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ffm5f9q/3/) to show you my attempt.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var events = 13;
var num = 1;

for(var i = 1; i <= events; i++) {
  $('<div class="anyEventDiv" id="anyDiv' + i + '">'
    + '<div class="check"><span>N' + i + '</span></div></div>').appendTo(".container");
}

if(events > 6) {
  $('<div class="sliderLeft">left</div>').prependTo(".container");
  $('<div class="sliderRight">right</div>').appendTo(".container");

  for(var y = 7; y <= events; y++) {
    $("#anyDiv" + y).css("display", "none");
  }
}

$(".sliderRight").on('click', function() {
  if(num <= (events - 6)) {
    $("#anyDiv" + (6 + num)).css("display", "table-cell");
    $("#anyDiv" + num).css("display", "none");

    num++;
  }
});

$(".sliderLeft").on('click', function() {
  if(num > 1) {
    $("#anyDiv" + (6 + num - 1)).css("display", "none");
    $("#anyDiv" + (num - 1)).css("display", "table-cell");

    num--;
  }
});
});
```

I want my slider to be activated when there are more than 6 events occurring. This is why I only add arrows when the count is more than 6. In the example, I set the number of events as a variable I could change to maintain the flow more easily.

Now, I have managed to do it by sliding one event at a time, either to the right or back to the left. This was easy. Where it gets tricky is when I want to display a whole new block of 6 elements by clicking the right button. And the total number of my events is not always a multiple of 6, it could be 13, for instance. In this case, I have to show the remainder of the division and slide the last elements which are going to be fewer than 6, for my total number will not a multiple of 6. The left arrow should also return blocks of 6 elements at a time.

I know a similar functionality exists with Bootstrap's carousel, but unfortunately it doesn't work in a similar fashion and I will end up writing my own solution to the problem instead.

On a side note, I am curious if this handmade, no-framework solution could be animated similarly to Bootstrap's carousel.

Thanks in advance for the assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I played a lot with the scenario. I don't know if the answer would be of interest to anyone, there was a person who got interested nevertheless. Here is what I did with jQuery ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ffm5f9q/144/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var events = 13;
var num = 0;
var rem = events % 6;

for(var i = 1; i <= events; i++) {
  $('<div class="anyEventDiv" id="anyDiv' + i + '">'
    + '<div class="check"><span>N' + i + '</span></div></div>').appendTo(".container");
}

if(events > 6) {
  $('<div class="sliderLeft">left</div>').prependTo(".container");
  $('<div class="sliderRight">right</div>').appendTo(".container");

  for(var y = 7; y <= events; y++) {
    $("#anyDiv" + y).css("display", "none");
  }
}

$(".sliderRight").on('click', function() {
  if(events - 6 - num >= 6) {
    for(var k = 1; k <= 6; k++) {
      $("#anyDiv" + (6 + num + k)).css("display", "table-cell");
      $("#anyDiv" + (num + k)).css("display", "none");
    }

    num = num + 6;
  }
  else {
    for(var k = 1; k <= rem; k++) {
      $("#anyDiv" + (6 + num + k)).css("display", "table-cell");
      $("#anyDiv" + (num + k)).css("display", "none");
    }
  }
});

$(".sliderLeft").on('click', function() {
  if(num > 1) {
    for(var k = 0; k <= 5; k++) {
      $("#anyDiv" + (6 + num + rem - k)).css("display", "none");
      $("#anyDiv" + (num + rem - k)).css("display", "table-cell");
    }

    num = num - 6;
  }
  else {
    for(var k = 1; k <= rem; k++) {
      $("#anyDiv" + (k + 6)).css("display", "none");
      $("#anyDiv" + k).css("display", "table-cell");
    }
  }
});
});
```

I've been unable to animate the whole thing, however. I would welcome a suggestion. At least this jQuery snippet did what I wanted programatically.